# Cannot Use Unallocated Space

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, disk-space, raid-5, partition-magic

I have a Dell T7600 workstation with four 1.82 TB drives in a RAID 5 configuration. Here is a diagram from MegaRAID storage manager:

[image]

Given space for parity, this leaves me with approximately 5.5 TB of space to allocate. I understand Windows limits a single partition to 2 TB. My partitions are arranged thusly:

[image]

I have three blocks of unallocated space I'd like to use. The first is 4 MB in between the FAT and the E:RECOVERY partition. The second is a very tiny 1 MB block between the C: drive and the larger unallocated partition of 3539.5 GB. I am unable to completely remove or allocate any of the three unallocated partitions. I've got the native Windows 10 Disk Management tool, and I tried the free Partition Wizard 9.1 MiniTool as well. If I try to create a partition in the larger space, I am only given .88 MB to use! Partition Wizard doesn't even show the 1mb space in the table (I ended up with this tiny bit of space because I extended the C: drive into that space hoping to utilize all of it. To my surprise, I couldn't use the entire block!

How do I absorb the remaining blocks of unallocated space, or combine them or move them? If I try to create a partition in the 4MB space it only ends up being 3MB with another 1MB block of unallocated space in front of it.

Comment: the other limitation you can be getting is minimum file tables sizes, alignment even if not an "advanced format" drive and isnt cylinder alignment still in play for partition walls?  Then the block size of any raid that works that way. and cluster size , which does not come into play yet.  I dont really know, just that usually you cant just add a sector or 2 here and there with the partition walls, it moves in larger chunks.  Moving the partition (with re-alignment) would be the common way to shift an unallocated space (small or not).  Moving needs backup of the data, and moves data,takes time

Comment: I'm not given the option to move them, which seems odd to me. Even the small ones. I'm reflecting on cloning the thing to a smaller drive with Macrium and doing away with the Perc controller and just going off the SATA port. The way it is now is a waste of disk space.

Comment: That way I can clone everything but the dead space and configure the way I want it distributed on the target drive.

Comment: I think windows only does minor sizing stuff and completly safe moves and all, "pro" versions of various parititoning sofftware provide for all that control, and a real "move" of a partition is done completly offline, and can take loads of time when there is data there. The massive data movement , and the partition table correlation need, makes it dangerous  (i prefer to complete all this once, before fill, but have done it many times filled Yawwn)

Comment: 3rd party partitioning software also seems to show better what is really going on, provides for better visual GUI bumping of the sizes you can use, automatically aligns important stuff this week (as some of that changed) , and can give better Hover information, combined with help files, and listed execution activity that will "need" to occur

Comment: the right disk cloning software would allow for the partition tables to be altered prior to the cloning, as long as it fits within the data sizes. Imaging partitions instead, you could clone one by one , to your own new parition design , either way . . . as long as there is still a backup :-)   
  Last note: "dynamic" disk windows partitioning does allow for more flexability, IMO though it can create virtual messes too.

Comment: If I stay with MBR partitions, there's no way around the 2tb limit, is there? I have to go with GPT?

Comment: There is a way around the 2T limit for MBR (but dont tell anybody and i am not recommending it)  Because your on a raid hardware device (be that the intel or add-on card) a raid array can be created using less than the whole disk(s) <2T, then a second array can use the rest of the disk(s), and wala the 2 arrays defined before the OS gets there can then have a smaller MBR array and be booted to still.  I still apply that method for shortstroke arrays only , and have moved to GPT mostly like i am suppsed to.  Any fear of GPT I had dissolved as it is error free still

Comment: I downloaded AOMEI Partition Assistant and will convert to a GPT partition. I think that's the best option. Interestingly, AOMEI doesn't even list the little 1mb of unallocated space in the graphical representation of the drive. Just seems odd that it would show in the native Windows disk manager but not in AOMEI.